# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm attempting to compile my app with a hosted CI service using xctool. I'm seeing this error during my build:

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'
```

I'm not seeing this when compiling in Xcode (it compiles and code signs perfectly fine).

Here is the command that I'm executing:

```
xctool ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -scheme "ShipIOWatchTest" -sdk "iphoneos" -workspace "ShipIOWatchTest.xcworkspace" clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Andrew Page (**********)"
```

I believe that I have proper configuration within Xcode. Here are my settings:

**Main App Team Selection**
[image: Main App Team Settings]

**Project CodeSigning Settings**
[image: Project Codesign]

**Main App CodeSigning Settings**
[image: App Codesign]

**Watch Extension CodeSigning Settings**
[image: Extension Codesign]

**Watch App CodeSigning Settings**
[image: Watch App Codesign]

This is very frustrating. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to build your "Test" Target?  In your build command, you seem to be specifying a test scheme `ShipIOWatchTest`, which may have different code signing settings than your main project.

Comment: Googlers: [see if this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic)