# Error Code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'watchOS 4.0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchos

Since I update Xcode for IOS 11, I can't sign my previous app which include WatchKit OS. The error is :

> Code signing is required for product type 'WatchKit Extension' in SDK 'watchOS 4.0'

What could cause such error message?

Comment: [Abandoned relevant question with no answer (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484952/codesign-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-watchkit-extension-i) (for the record)

Comment: let us know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic) helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic)